# Django and  tinymce 

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm starting out with django, and I'm using James Bennett's guid on Django.

I'm at page 42 now and I need to include tinymce into change_form.html. So I added the following lines :

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
(r'^tiny_mce/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            { 'document_root': 'C:/www/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/' }),
(r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
(r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
```

My template definition:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
   "C:/www/django/templates"

)
```

I created several directories into my templates dir :

```
C:\www\django\templates\admin\flatpage\flatpages
```

I added the javascript to the change_form.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
mode: "textareas",
theme: "simple"
});
</script>
```

However I don't get any rich text editor options on my editing page. Is there anyone that has run into this problem ?

Comment: I know you are using the guide and probably want to stick to it, but there are better ways to add TinyMCE: https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the terminal log when your project is running do you get any `404 errors`?
It could be that the tinymce javascript is just not loading.

Make sure your `urls.py` allow for the loading of static and media content.
Something like this should work if that is the problem:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$',
         'django.views.static.serve',
         {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True, }),
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$',
         'django.views.static.serve',
         {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True, }),
)
```

You'll probably then change your `<script type="text/javascript" src="/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>` to `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>` The book you are using doesn't cater for static files because that is new to django 1.3. So if you are using django 1.3 you will have it as static but if you are sticking to the book and the version of < 1.3 then it'll all be MEDIA_URL

On the topic of the book you are using. I ran into a few issues with it (code being incorrect or outdated) Here are some links that will help you while you work your way through the book.

1. http://www.gyford.com/phil/writing/2010/01/14/django.php (Source code)
2. http://blog.haydon.id.au/2008/08/notes-on-practical-django-projects.html (chapter by chapter help)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure tiny_mce.js is loaded? Try browse source code and open tiny_mce.js link

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AddWYSIWYGEditor

See number 3.

Comment: The problem is I haven't got the admin.py in my project prackage. Also it doesn't get loaded, I checked the source.

Comment: you can create it. you can put it in models but it's not recommended as far i know.